# Sharing Internet over LAN

Tags: internet

I have joined a lab where 6 computers are connected with a switch and share the Internet access from one of them, all the machines use Windows 7.

After formatting the main PC which shared the Internet connection, no one can access the Internet, I have tried to fix the problem already.

I have already enabled ICS (Internet Connection Sharing)

My client PC has a different network name.

LAN:

- PC1 has 2 networks [1 unidentified and 1 network]
- PC2 and PC4 have [network 2]
- PC3 and PC5 have [network 3]

How can I share the Internet connection over this LAN?

Comment: Any reason you can't just get a router?

Comment: A router costs ~20 dollars these days. That's a little over 3.50 dollars per person. Hook up the switch to one of the router ports. Benefit.

Comment: Really  As noted an inexpensive router solves the issue and add some possible benefits

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem! Do the machines that can't access the Internet get IP addresses assigned? Can they `ping` the main machine on its private address? What happens if they `tracert` out to the Internet by IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that all the Client machines are set to either automatically find the Host IP or manually set the host IP..

I've not done much networking in windows 7 but I would assume they would make it pretty easy. don't know if this helps > http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

Answer (score 0):

I assume this means the one "serving" the internet has multiple network adapters?

Have you tried bridging them?